# Selenium Get Element By Id Which Is Inside Another Element Without Xpath

Tags: selenium, webdriver, element, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am working on a small automation project.
The website that I am working on, has a weird design. It has multiple elements with the same id. And the website works as expected(multiple same id's don't cause any problem on anything)
I need to reach all of these elements, but I can't, since their id's are all the same.
The only way I can reach all of them is to use "full xpath", but this solution won't be a long term solution, since only adding a single div to the website will cause the full xpath not work properly.

I want to reach the element with the outer element like:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classs")
for element in elements:
    element.find_element_by_id("idOfElement")
    #OR
    element.find_element_by_class_name("classOfTheElement"
```

THIS IS NOT A WORKING CODE, I just wanted to make you understand what I want.
Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
The website has a series of elements which is to upload variants of an object, and the id's in these variants are the same. I need to reach these id'ed elements and send some keys. Here is a similar html tree:

```
<div class="generalClass">
    <div class="someElement">
        <input id="idOfInput>
    </div>
    <div class="someElement">
        <input id="idOfInput>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the url to that page and mention what elements are you exactly looking for?

Comment: @Prophet The website needs a registration which needs an API from another website, which means it is hard. I edited a sample html part that is similar to my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use absolute XPaths, this can be clearly done with relative XPath.
Accordingly to your example you can do the following:

```
outer_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("classs")
desired_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//input[@id='idOfInput']")
```

or even more simply with a single relative XPath:

```
desired_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="classs"]//input[@id="idOfInput"]')
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the relationship between outer_element and desired_elements, how are they connected? But the single relative path solves the problem.

Comment: It's actually exactly the same. In the first way I locate the outer div element and after that I search inside / below it. That is what  `.` is coming for there, saying like "from THIS NODE find elements located with the following locator". The second XPath doing the same: locate element matching `//div[@class="classs"]` and inside it locate element(s) located by `//input[@id="idOfInput"]`

Answer (score 1):

Some times `id` is not available in the elements and a single class is shared with other elements as well so `xpath` is a better option, you can find the xpath of the element using inspect in developers tools and in case you are writing path on your own you can verify if it points to correct element or not, here is how

1. Right click then inspect
2. `ctrl` `+` `F`
3. Enter you path/selector
4. Click `Enter`

It will highlight the selected element.